# List all installed packages from a certain repository in ubuntu / debian

Tags: debian, awk, repository

How to list all packages that *I have installed* from a certain repository in ubuntu / debian without using any exotic command, even the `aptitude`, just basic ones, like `apt list --installed`, or from [here](https://superuser.com/a/200505/203539):

List all of your current repositories:

`apt-cache policy | sed -n 's/.*o=\([^,]\+\).*/\1/p' | uniq`

and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1013644/227355),

```
for p in $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/{ print $2 }'); do for i in $(apt-cache policy "$p" | awk '/Installed/{ print $2}'); do apt-cache policy "$p" | grep -A1 '\*\*\*\ '$i'' | if grep -q jessie; then echo $p; fi; done; done
```

Not saying the latter is the solution as even the author admitted that it is *"quite ugly"*, but the approach of just using basic tools is good.

Or, maybe, the best approach is to write an `awk` scripts to parse some `apt` installation log(s)?

BTW, why I want to know -- Here all of my current repositories:

```
LP-PPA-myid,a=focal
cloudsmith/myid/repo,a=bullseye
Docker,a=bullseye
Google LLC,a=stable
Debian,a=oldstable
Debian,a=testing
Debian Backports,a=bullseye-backports
Debian,a=stable-security
Debian,a=stable
```

But somehow I don't know why the nodejs repo is not in the list:

```
$ apt-cache policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 16.18.1-deb-1nodesource1
  Candidate: 16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1
  Version table:
     16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x bullseye/main amd64 Packages
 *** 16.18.1-deb-1nodesource1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     12.22.5~dfsg-2~11u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```